# An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Pipe Vault.exe

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This code for my Commit button was working most of the time yesterday the way that it is written below. Yesterday I periodically would get this exception, but today I get it everytime. Its failing on:

Dim newRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("PV_Table").NewRow()

It's saying newRow is Nothing, how can I fix this and what should it be?

```
Private Sub btnCommit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCommit.Click


    Dim newRow As DataRow = ds.Tables("PV_Table").NewRow()
    Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    cb.QuotePrefix = "["
    cb.QuoteSuffix = "]"

    newRow("Location") = txtLocation.Text
    newRow("Project Name") = txtProjectName.Text
    newRow("Pipe Date") = txtPipeDate.Text
    newRow("Pipe Number") = txtPipeNumber.text
    newRow("Pipe Size") = txtPipeSize.Text
    newRow("Aprox Footage") = txtAproxFootage.Text
    newRow("Install Date") = txtInstallDate.Text

    ds.Tables("PV_Table").Rows.Add(newRow)
    da.Update(ds, "PV_Table")
    Me.PV_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PVdbDataSet.PV_Table)    'DataGridView Binding

    'SET UP THE PROVIDER
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS
    TheDatabase = "/PVdb.accdb"
    MyFolder = "C:\Pipe Vault"
    FullDatabasePath = MyFolder & TheDatabase

    'SET THE DATA SOURCE
    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

    'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    'OPEN THE DATABASE
    con.Open()

    'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER
    sql = "SELECT * FROM PV_table"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "PV_Table")

    'Close THE DATABASE  '
    con.Close()

    'ENABLES TEXT BOXES
    For Each a In Me.Controls
        If TypeOf a Is TextBox Then
            a.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next

    'CLEARS CONTENTS OF TEXT BOXES
    txtLocation.Clear()
    txtProjectName.Clear()
    txtPipeDate.Clear()
    txtPipeNumber.Clear()
    txtPipeSize.Clear()
    txtAproxFootage.Clear()
    txtInstallDate.Clear()

    'SETS STATES OF BUTTONS
    btnCommit.Enabled = False
    btnAddNew.Enabled = True
    btnUpdate.Enabled = False
    btnDelete.Enabled = False


End Sub
```

I found in my Form Load event that I had the same code under the Comment 'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER. It was all commented out. I uncommented them and it seems to be working again.

```
Public Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.PV_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.PVdbDataSet.PV_Table)

    'SET UP THE PROVIDER
    dbProvider = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;"

    'SET THE DATABASE AND WHERE THE DATABASE IS
    TheDatabase = "/PVdb.accdb"
    MyFolder = "C:\Pipe Vault"
    FullDatabasePath = MyFolder & TheDatabase

    'SET THE DATA SOURCE
    dbSource = "Data Source = " & FullDatabasePath

    'SET THE CONNECTION STRING
    con.ConnectionString = dbProvider & dbSource

    'OPEN THE DATABASE
    con.Open()

    'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER
    sql = "SELECT * FROM PV_table"
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, con)
    da.Fill(ds, "PV_Table")


    'Close THE DATABASE  '
    con.Close()
    'MessageBox.Show("Database is now closed")


    DataGridView1.GridColor = Color.Red





End Sub
```

Comment: My first guess would be that `ds.Tables("PV_Table")` is `Nothing`.  Can you try assigning that to a separate variable, and set a breakpoint right after it?  What does the variable contain after executing?

Comment: What type of variable should I declare it as? I'm really new at this stuff so bare with me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Use a DataTable: `Dim tbl As DataTable = ds.Tables("PV_Table")`, then change the next line to `Dim newRow As DataRow = tbl.NewRow()`. Then set a break point on the second line.  When the debugger hits that breakpoint, hover over the variable `tbl` to see what its value is.

Comment: It says "Nothing" when I hover on tbl.

Comment: Ok  - so that means that for some reason your data source "PV_Table" isn't getting created and filled with data.  You have to look at the code where that's getting filled initially.  It should be similar to the lines in your code underneath the comment `'STORE THE SQL STRING AND CONNECTION OBJECT TO THE DATA_ADAPTER`.  That part of your `Commit_Click` method seems to be refreshing the data.   There should be some code that fills it _initially_.

Comment: Also - There must be some line before the PV_Table gets filled, that actually creates and assigns a data table to PV_Table; like `ds.Tables("PV_Table") = New DataTable`

Comment: So my Commit_Click was basically trying to refresh some thing that wasn't there?

Comment: Yes, pretty much... actually it was crashing when you were trying to add a new row to a DataTable that didn't exist.  Looks like you found the answer, great!  It is OK on Stack Overflow to answer your own question and accept it as the correct answer (though you won't get points for it).  Paste the part of the text that answers your question in the "Your Answer" box, and click the checkbox to accept it.  That way, if someone is looking for the same issue, they'll see that it's answered.

Comment: Thanks for your help. You explained in a clear way that allowed me to understand and learn.

Comment: Glad to help whenever I can!